# I accidentally opened a localhost port?

Tags: security, firewall, port, malware, localhost

I had accidentally opened a port via firewall which had a WEBSITE(IIS EXPRESS) localhost port number. So could my desktop be hacked by opening a port? And also i had deleted it after a few minutes.

Comment: It depends which OS you're using, port and what service was running on that port during the exposure.

Comment: Which port did you open? Is there a program listening on the port? Where is the Firewall running (on PC or external)? What do you mean with localhost? Really "Localhost" or "local host"=PC?

Comment: Is the firewall running on your desktop, or is it a separate device?  If it's separate then there is no way to open up the non-routable localhost addresses (like 127.0.0.1).

Comment: You're most likely fine by the sounds of things - I doubt someone was actively attempting to infiltrate your home PC.

Comment: it was an IIS EXPRESS local host for website

Comment: It's **very** unlikely any harm was done if it was only open for a few minutes.

Answer (score 2):

If you're behind a firewall (common ISP router) don't worry, unless a NAT/PAT on that router no one reached you.
Also, if with localhost you mean you binded it to localhost, only connections from the same machine could be happened.

Don't worry anyway.

Comment: could you elaborate a bit as i was trying to connect my phone to the local host by opening a port (having the same wifi network) and also its a d-link wifi router